# What youth organizations are dedicated to animal rights and veganism?

Tags: veganism, outreach, animal-welfare

Seeking assistance identifying youth organizations that are actively involved in animal rights advocacy and promoting veganism. Details such as name, location, mission, and notable projects are valuable. Please feel free to include national and international organizations.

Share any personal experiences or recommendations regarding specific organizations, as well as any ongoing volunteering opportunities, campaigns, events, or online communities.